# Complete User Name and Password on a Site

Tags: php, html

Me Again

This is off topic and I was wondering if anyone could give some direction in this

I have a website we use for our tracking company the website doesn't belong to us but we have access to the site via a Username and Password. I was wondering is there away that I can write a code that it automatically inserts our username and password into the fields of our supplier's website on clicking a button on our website diverting to that site.

The site in I want to link to is www.gpsyeah.com

Basically I want to see if it is possible to auto complete the user name and password

Logic says I will not be able to as I cannot Echo on another site but maybe there is a clever one here who knows how to do this

Comment: Did not get exactly what do you want, you need CURL to do the login to remote site for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fill in forms on other websites.

What you can do is create a GET url or a POST form that points to that site.

Comment: Agree Logic says you cannot complete a form you don't have access to. Pointing to the site is the easy part but completing that form would not be that easy and would be considered as a robot basically completing forms

Comment: I'm not sure what you wanted to say. PHP is your robot?